# Accessing global variable in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to access the global variable in a function but i get different result.

When I run this code my output is:

```
5.00000
0.00000
```

What I want is to access the global variable data in function `generateData` function which is `20` and `5`.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// global variable that thread will use

int data_count, thread_count,  bin_count;  
float equalDivisionCount, max_meas, min_meas;
float* data;
int* bin_counts; // final count of element in each bin
float* bin_maxes; // to hold the maximum boundary value of each bin
int* intermediateBinCounts; // hold the data of individial bin in each thread with a offset

void generateData();

struct privateDataInfo {
    int starting;
    int endingIndex;
    int index;
};

void main() {
    thread_count = 4;
    data_count = 14;
    bin_count = 4;

    max_meas = 20;
    max_meas = 5;

    data = (float *)malloc(data_count * sizeof(float));
    bin_counts = (int *)malloc(bin_count * sizeof(float));
    bin_maxes = (float *)malloc(data_count * sizeof(float));
    intermediateBinCounts = (int *)malloc(bin_count * thread_count * sizeof(int));

    int lastElement = 0;

    struct privateDataInfo s1[thread_count];
    generateData();
}

void generateData() {
    printf("%f\n", max_meas);
    printf("%f", min_meas);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile!  The compiler outputs a long string of warnings.  Suggest enabling the warnings, then fix those warnings

Comment: regarding: `void main(){`  there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: i am sorry, i am new to this, do you mean main can only be called with this parameter?

Comment: to start, NEVER call `main()` from your program.  Just use one of the two valid signatures for `main()`

Comment: @pravinpoudel -- `struct privateDataInfo s1[thread_count];` -- This is not C++, but you tagged the question as C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant expression, not a runtime value.  In C++, usage of `std::vector` is done to easily support dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 3):

This

```c
  max_meas = 20;
  max_meas = 5;
```

should be this

```c
  max_meas = 20;
  min_meas = 5;
```

Comment: thank you i know this is silly but i couldn't get it with my eye so i posted the question.

Thank you again

Comment: Happens to everyone once in a while